# Image BoxFit.cover is not applied correctly

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fill the whole screen with 4-equal-size images (2x2) with the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(_MyApp());

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, the result is this:
[image]

The result I'm looking for:
[image]

How can I fix my code to do it? So each image has same size as others, and view as 2X2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply each image with `height: double.infinity` to make the image takes as many as possible height:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(_MyApp());

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: double.infinity,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: double.infinity,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: double.infinity,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: double.infinity,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **fit** property, use: `fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,`.

See in documentation also: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html